# Exporting mysql database from wampserver using vb6

Tags: mysql, vb6, wamp, wampserver

Im having a problem exporting a mysql database from wampserver. Im using the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdBackup_Click()
Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass
    DoEvents

    cmd = Chr(34) & "C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\Documents\Clients\Darwin\mysql\mysqldump" & Chr(34) & "mysqldump.exe -uroot -p -hlocalhost school > c:\a.sql"
    Call execCommand(cmd)

    Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

As expected, an .sql file was created in my C:/. But for unknown reason, the created sql file is empty (literally empty, 0 byte, no texts inside).

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance! Sorry for my english.

Comment: does windows and the capability to redirect data? I think not

Comment: Sorry sir but I dont get you? What do you mean capability to redirect data?

Comment: he means your > in the cmd - this is a redirect

Comment: What does `execCommand` return? true or false? You should check for it to find the error

Comment: Try quoting your path to mysqldump

Comment: @kenkenXD yes, the symbol you used `>` is a redirect in linux and unix, seems you just copied the command from linux. but it is hard to transplant from linux to windows just using command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if that code should work its been years since I used VB6 but one obvious problem I can see is that when you execute this statement,

```
mysqldump.exe -uroot -p -hlocalhost school > c:\a.sql
```

the `mysqlsump.exe` will see the `-p` parameter and be expecting a password to be entered from the console. Try it manually from a command window!

I am guessing there is no console and if there was the user should not know the password to the `root` account anyway.

The quick solution would be to change the code to:

```
mysqldump.exe -uroot -pSuperUsersPassword -hlocalhost school > c:\a.sql
```

but that is a **major security nightmare** as you have hardcoded the MySQL Super Users password in a piece of code. Remember MySQL is a proper DBMS and can manage many different databases, not just the one you are using.

Also if the password is ever changed you must remember to change this code at the same time, **a maintenance nightmare**.

At the very least you should create a new user account in MySQL that has access to only this one database and has only the privilages to do backups (`SELECT, SHOW DATABASES, LOCK TABLES, EVENT`). Then at least you are not giving away the Crown Jewels to anyone that can see your source code or can read a hex dump of your executable.